# Inquiry about Writing Style in a Book

Tags: header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr

I recently came across a book online and was captivated by its writing style. I've been trying to emulate it using LaTeX, and I've attached some sample pages along with the code I've attempted so far.

I've made some updates to my code and would greatly appreciate it if you could take a look:

http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/ttf/cmr10.ttf

http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/ttf/cmbx12.ttf

Furthermore, I've identified the following fonts from the PDF in question:

1. CMBX10 CMBX12 CMBX9 CMCSC10 CMEX10 CMMI10 CMMI12 CMMI5 CMMI6 CMMI7
   CMMI8 CMMI9 CMR10 CMR12 CMR17 CMR5 CMR6 CMR7 CMR8 CMR9 CMSY10 CMSY5
   CMSY6 CMSY7 CMSY8 CMSY9 CMTI10 CMTI9 MSBM10 MinionPro-Regular
   Tex-cmex9 Times-Roman

```
    \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    
    \setmainfont{cmr10}[
        Extension = .ttf,
        Path = ./,  % Path to the font file
    ]
    
    \newfontfamily\chapterfont{cmbx12}[
        Extension = .ttf,
        Path = ./,  % Path to the font file
    ]
    
    \newfontfamily\chapternumberfont{cmr17}[
        Extension = .ttf,
        Path = ./,  % Path to the font file
    ]
    
    \titleformat{\chapter}[block]
        {\Huge\bfseries\chapterfont}{\chapternumberfont\thechapter}{10pt}{#1}
    
    \titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
        {\Huge\bfseries\chapterfont}{}{0pt}{#1}
    
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{$L^{p}$ Spaces and Banach Spaces}
    \lipsum[4]
    \end{document}
```

which produces the following fonts:

CMMI12 CMBX12 CMR10 CMR17

[image]

I was hoping someone could provide guidance on how to achieve a similar style. Your insights would be greatly appreciated!
Here is source of document.
[assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9627.pdf](https://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9627.pdf)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The `article` class won't get you where you want to go if you want chapters.  Only `book`and similar classes have `\chapter`s.

Comment: Perhaps its was written in Latex: have you contacted the author(s) or publisher?

Comment: Change `article` by a book-like document class (e.g., `book`, `memoir`, `scrbook`, etc.) and `\section` by `\chapter`. Setting of chapter and table of contents styles could be different depending  of the document class, via packages or specific commands for each class.

Comment: as you have the pdf, https://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9627.pdf, presumably you can check what fonts it uses, and use the same it was produced with tex and dvipdfm

Comment: @DavidCarlisle good idea thank you, but I'm not familiar with dvipdfm,  can you give me an example of it

Comment: it just means they used latex to dvi them dvipdfm to make pdf, the tex source would look same if it were for pdftex, the point is you can certainly make exactly that layout using tex as the book was done with tex

Comment: I updated my code check it please

Comment: Don't use `lmodern` with `fontspec`.

Comment: remove all those font settings,  if you are using xelatex or lualatex you are already using latin modern which is essentially an opentype version of computer modern already. so you also can remove the lmodern package

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank u, but what is the fonts used on the document on question

Comment: @cfr I will modify it

Comment: @IvanGozard You've got the PDF; you know the fonts. Most viewers will list them. Otherwise `\pdffonts`. By the way, the link doesn't work because you've included a comma.

Comment: please, see my updated

Comment: as you show the document is mostly just using standard latex default cm fonts so you do not need to specify anything. if you use xelatex or lualatex you will get latin modern rather than cm, but that's the same design, just a different implementation (mostly). Just ignore the fonts completely and concentrate on the layout.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle 
thank you for your clarification.

Comment: You need to break what you're trying to do down into discrete steps. E.g. the chapter title, the epigraphs, the table of contents etc. Then tackle one at a time and ask a specific question if you get stuck, with code showing what you've tried. Or, alternatively, edit this question to focus on the feature of the layout you're interested in and explain how you're trying to implement it. (Or just ask the author if they have a style file as suggested above.)